# How do I iterate over a queue, adding and deleting elements as I go?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to be able to iterate over a queue, each time adding some new elements to the queue, but removing elements that I have dealt with.

```
queue = [[0,8],[1,2],[2,4]]

for [x,y] in queue
    for i in [1,2,3]
        # Do something that results in a new coordinate..
        queue.push([newx,newy])
```

The problem is, I am not sure what the best way to do this would be.

If I delete each element from the array as I iterate, it leaves an empty element in the array.

If I copy the array, empty it by doing `queue.length = 0` and then iterate over the copy, that won't work because doing a slice to copy doesn't work when the array contains objects.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: First, don't use a `for … in` loop to iterate over array elements, use an ordinary `for` loop instead. Second, it's not totally clear to me what you want (as result), but perhaps that's only me, as I'm rather tired.

Comment: I don't understand.. what's wrong with using `for .. in`? It allows me to specify what variable name to assign the element to, or even unpack it like with `for [x,y] in queue`. The result I want, is that after iterating over `queue`, `queue` only contains the elements I have pushed into it, and none of the elements it contained before the iteration commenced.

Comment: [MDC says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description): “The `for...in` statement iterates over user-defined properties in addition to the array elements, so if you modify the array's non-integer or non-positive properties (e.g. by adding a `"foo"` property to it or even by adding a method or property to `Array.prototype`), the `for...in` statement will return the name of your user-defined properties in addition to the numeric indexes. Also, because order of iteration is arbitrary, iterating over an array may not visit elements in numeric order.”

Comment: And to add: can't you just push elements to a new array, while you iterate over the old one without deleting properties of it?

Comment: Ah, there's been some confusion.. this is CoffeeScript :)  .. the javascript it compiles to uses a `for` iterator loop.

Comment: `"can't you just push elements to a new array"`, ah, and then at the end `queue = temp_new_queue`? That sounds like it would do the job!

Comment: Yes, and I just saw you're using CoffeeScript (didn't recognize your code), which I don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is modify a copy of the array:

```
queue2 = queue.slice 0

for [x,y] in queue
  for i in [1,2,3]
    # generate newX and newY
    queue2.push([newx,newy])

queue = queue2
```

I'm not sure what you mean when you say

> that wont work because doing a slice to copy doesn't work when the array contains objects.

You may have been misled by something you read elsewhere. Using `slice` to do an array copy works perfectly well with objects:

```
coffee> queue = [[0,8],[1,2],[2,4]]
[ [ 0, 8 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ] ]
coffee> queue.slice 0
[ [ 0, 8 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ] ]
```

What it won't do is do a deep copy of the objects stored by the array. But since you're just doing insertions and deletions to `queue`, that's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the slicing, it *was* something I read elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
queue = [[0,8],[1,2],[2,4]]

for [x,y], i in queue
  queue[i] = [x-1,y+1]

console.log queue  #=> [ [ -1, 9 ], [ 0, 3 ], [ 1, 5 ] ]
```

`for`-`in` isn't suitable for operations that changes target's `.length` as it's cached beforehand. To update inline, you'd have to write like:

```
queue = [[0,8],[1,2],[2,4]]

i = -3
while point = queue[i += 3]
  [x,y] = point
  queue[i..i] = ([x-j,y+j] for j in [1,2,3])

console.log queue
#=> [[-1,9],[-2,10],[-3,11],[0,3],[-1,4],[-2,5],[1,5],[0,6],[-1,7]]
```

Comment: The problem is, each iteration may generate multiple new coordinate that need to be added to the queue.

Comment: I see. Then yep, pushing to a new array is an obvious solution (since Coffee doesn't allow [nested comprehensions](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1191)).

Comment: See the edit for non-obvious, esoteric, inefficient solution.